# How to update an asset file during OnCreate method

Tags: android, text, import, oncreate

I have stored a text file in main/asset. This contains relevant data for my application. I want to update (or replace) it in `MainActivity` in the `OnCreate` method. The new file is located on a server.

How can I update the file?

Feel free to make suggestions in case the approach storing the data in main/asset and updating it in the OnCreate method is too inconvenient.

Comment: Assets at runtime of your app are read only. Hence that file too. Rethink your scenario.

Comment: @blackapps: good to know, thank you! What is a handy scenario? Iam knew in the android world and have problems to imaging what is possible.

Comment: A much used scenario (you are not the first one who wants this) is to copy the file from assets to getFilesDir(). Only copy from assets if the file does not yet exist in getFilesDir(). After that check if the file on server is different/newer then the one in getFilesDir(). If so then download and overwrite that file.